# Fetching server results with Flex/ActionScript

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

I am trying to get the data provided by MyTSA (https://www.dhs.gov/mytsa-api-documentation) for security line wait times, but I am having trouble with it. Here is the code that I have:

```
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

            [Bindable]
            private var url:String = "http://apps.tsa.dhs.gov/MyTSAWebService/GetWaitTimes.ashx?output=xml&ap=SEA";

            protected function init(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                getWaits.send();
            }

            protected function getWaitsResult(event:ResultEvent):void
            {
                data_label.text = getWaits.lastResult.toString();               
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
        <s:HTTPService id="getWaits" url="{url}" result="getWaitsResult(event)"/>
```

Whenever I run it, I get the error code: `[RPC Fault faultString="HTTP request error" faultCode="Server.Error.Request" faultDetail="Error: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: http://apps.tsa.dhs.gov/MyTSAWebService/GetWaitTimes.ashx?output=xml?output=XML&ap=SEA" errorID=2032]. URL: http://apps.tsa.dhs.gov/MyTSAWebService/GetWaitTimes.ashx?output=xml?output=XML&ap=SEA"]`

Any idea how I can get this to work? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks,
Jacob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your url does not work. However, it seems that they have problems with their API. A lot of urls on that documentation page does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Someting in your app is changing the url to the following as per the error that you got.

http://apps.tsa.dhs.gov/MyTSAWebService/GetWaitTimes.ashx?output=xml?output=XML&ap=SEA

2032 error occurs when the url is wrong Or the return data is wrong. So, if you check the url above, `output=xml?output=XML` is wrong / bad url. You may have to rectify the url.